# « Play on (upon) an idea » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Comment dit-on « to play on (upon) an idea » en français ?  Je crois que c'est idiomatique, mais j'ai besoin d'une expression similaire.

[Définitions et exemples](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+on) :

> - to exploit something—including a word—for some purpose; to develop something for some purpose. (*Upon* is formal and less commonly used than *on*.) *You are just playing on words! You are playing on a misunderstanding*.
> - to have an effect on something; to manage something for a desired effect. (The *on* can be replaced by *upon*.) *The clerk played on my sense of responsibility in trying to get me to buy the book*. *See if you can get her to confess by playing on her sense of guilt.*

En français « avoir un effet sur quelque chose; obtenir un effet désiré de quelque chose », en l'occurrence, il s'agit d'une idée.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La formulation « **jouer sur** » existe belle et bien en français. Elle apparaît notamment dans l'expression « **jouer sur les mots** » (très fréquente en français).

Exemples :

- « **Tu joues sur les mots** pour me faire dire ce que je n'ai pas dit. »
  *You play on words to make me say what I didn't said.*
- « **Il joue sur** les sentiments pour obtenir ce qu'il désire. »
  *He plays on feelings to get what he desires.*
- « **Nous pouvons jouer sur l'idée selon laquelle** tu es très riche pour entrer. »
  *We can play on the idea that you are very rich to enter.*

Autres formulations :

- « **Tirer parti de l'idée** » est aussi envisageable. On pourra aussi dire dans un langage un peu soutenu « **exploiter l'idée** » ou encore, « **mettre à profit l'idée** ».

Pour caractériser l'idée, nous pourrons utiliser :

- « **l'idée selon laquelle** [cet accident est sans gravité] », dans le langage soutenu, et à l'écrit. Cette formulation est la plus « jolie ».
- « **l'idée disant que** [...] »  Cette formulation est légèrement maladroite.
- « **l'idée que** [cet accident n'est pas grave] » La formulation la plus rapide, mais aussi la plus maladroite.

Le but sera le plus généralement exprimé avec « pour », et « afin de ».

**Bilan :** Dans tout les cas, il me semble que l'expression la plus proche de « *play on the fact / the idea* », est : « *jouer sur le fait / l'idée* ».

Answer (score 3):

Je ne suis pas sûr qu'une seule expression soit valide dans tous les contextes.

"Jouer sur" est certainement possible. Par exemple, on lit souvent "Les idéologies extrêmes jouent sur les peurs des français" ("Extreme ideologies play on the fears of the French"). Mais son utilisation est un peu abstraite.

"Tirer parti de" parait une bonne approximation pour les deux phrases proposées, mais une traduction directe en anglais serait "To take advantage of", qui ne traduit qu'une partie du sens.